# Posting the same question on another website WITHOUT disclosure?

Tags: discussion

jxhyc also posted [Why are there grammars in languages in the first place?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/43304) at https://redd.it/qqwc4p, exactly the same. Personally I think this cross posting  can assist, if you're hankering more opinions. But is it ungracious not to disclose cross posts?

I would hate to spend  time and effort writing an answer, when someone else already answered it at the other post. This would be a complete waste of my time.

Answer (score 4):

There's no requirement that a question asked here never have been asked anywhere else before. I don't think it's ungracious or rude.

Furthermore, most answers written here are written after the question has already been 'answered', there can only be one first answer after all. I suggest you not worry about what others have already done, and simply think whether you can contribute something useful to a question, whether that's a new perspective, or else a clearer/more concise/more thorough answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think one should first think about why the "duplicate" close-reason exists. It's not because such questions are inherently lousy, it's because it's an abuse of SE resources to ask the same question here over and over. In other words, it's about taking seriously the idea that SE is a resource that can and should be used to advance knowledge. It's not that the question has never been asked before, it's that it hasn't been asked *here* before. The overwhelming majority of questions that are asked here are asked and answered elsewhere, though generally in a more advanced venue.